# Не подключается скрипт js wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, css

Пытаюсь добавить скрипт js на wordpress, но он не подключается. CSS подключился спокойно, а вот js никак. Подскажите что не так с кодом?

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 
   function () {
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.css' );

wp_enqueue_script( 'app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/app.js', 'null', 
true );
});


add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );

?>
```

Comment: Третий параметр должен быть массивом, если там не должно быть зависимостей, то это должен быть просто пустой массив `[]`, четвертый параметр -- версия (строка), а только пятый -- булево значение (выводить в футере или нет).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
function test_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('app', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'app.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_script');

function my_test_function() {
    test_script();
}
```